# grails findAll() method

Tags: grails, find, hadoop, hsqldb, hbase

I am using the `findAll()` SQL-like method:

```
MyDomainClass.findAll("firstname='George' and lastname='kuo' and username='kjlop'"),
```

but I have got problem:

when value starts with number(for example,when age='2poj') it throws an exception

I use grails 1.3.2 and gorm-hbase 0.2.4 plugin and in my domain classes fields have `String` type.

Here is the Stack Trace:
expecting token in range: '0'..'9', found 'p'

```
at org.grails.hbase.ghql.LexerRules.nextToken(LexerRules.java:125)

at org.grails.hbase.finders.QueryStringTokenizer.tokenize(QueryStringTokenizer.groovy:59)

at org.grails.hbase.finders.TokenizerStrategy$tokenize.call(Unknown Source)
    //---------
```

I wonder is there any way in groovy change findAll() method work ?

If anybody know solution please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can hardly believe #1 - the HQL statement is properly quoted. Is it exactly the code you're using? #2 should also work. What if you try it on hsql? 3. Can you try MyDomainClass.findAllByFirstnameAndLastname('George', 'kuo')? It should work for every simple type then, including enums.

Comment: @Victor thank you for reply...I have tried MyDomainClass.findAllByFirstnameAndLastname() method and it worked in case, when value started with number, but it did not work with enum value.

Comment: besides it I have to find with multiple properties..

Answer (score 1):

You can try like the [Grails example](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html):

```
MyDomainClass.findAll("from DomainTable as b where b.firstname=:firstname and b.age=:age", [firstname:'Dan Brown', age: 25]
```

Notice: I don't know if you mistype it, but '25' is a string, so that it can't be `age='25'`

**EDIT:**
I don't know how this doesn't work, but in case you want to find with multiple properties, you should use [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)().

```
def c = MyDomainClass.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    like("firstName", "George%")
    like("age", "25");
}
```

**EDIT2:** Sorry, createCriteria is not supported by hbase plugin. Based on your condition, I think it's suitable to try DynamicFinderFilter (with approriate import).

```
// all books written by Dan Brown or J K Rowling
   DynamicFinderFilter filterList = new FinderFilterList(Operator.OR)

   DynamicFinderFilter filter1 = new Filter('author', 'Dan Brown')
   filterList.addFilter(filter1)

   DynamicFinderFilter filter2 = new Filter('author', 'J K Rowling')
   filterList.addFilter(filter12)

   results = Book.findAll(filterList)
```

The complete example can be find in the [plugin page](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gorm-hbase#descriptionTab).

Comment: @Hoàng Long in my domain class all field have String type...I have tried MyDomainClass.findAll("from DomainTable as b where b.firstname=:firstname and b.age=:age", [firstname:'Dan Brown', age: 25]), but it does not work...I have tried find this syntax in hbase documentation, but did not find [link]http://www.grails.org/plugin/gorm-hbase ...I think it does not support it.

Comment: @Bella: Maybe I remembered it wrong someway. Never mind, I think you can use createCriteria() for the same result:

Comment: @Hoàng Long it does not work...I guess, hbase does not support criteria too.

Comment: @Bella: sorry I don't read carefully. I think you have another option: the "FinderFilterList"(http://www.grails.org/plugin/gorm-hbase#descriptionTab).

Comment: @Hoàng Long: yes I can use Filters..it work properly, when first letter is number, but they are not so flexible, because I have to use 'OR' or 'AND'for few filters.

Comment: I wonder is there any way in groovy change findAll() method ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run a [dynamic finder method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) on the domain object to achieve what you need.

**Example:**

```
MyDomainClass.findAllByFirstnameAndAge('Dan', 25)
```

This works for all data types and enums.

Comment: @Benjiamin it works, but I have to find with multiple properties (for example: MyDomainClass.findAll("username='12a58n' and firstname= 'George' and lastname='Kuo' and (City='myCity' or City='hisCity')") )